# WHEN A SEQUENCE 1ST TIME APPLY WITH INSERT STATEMENT IT START FROM 2 WHILE STARTWITH NOT DEFINE IT SHOULD START FROM 1 BUT NOT

Tags: oracle11g, insert, sequence

WHEN A SEQUENCE 1ST TIME APPLY WITH INSERT STATEMENT IT START FROM 2 WHILE STARTWITH NOT DEFINE IT SHOULD START FROM 1 BUT NOT

```
CREATE TABLE ORA(ID NUMBER);
SELECT * FROM ORA;

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_ORA;
INSERT INTO ORA VALUES(SEQ_ORA.NEXTVAL);
SELECT * FROM ORA;
INSERT INTO ORA VALUES(SEQ_ORA.CURRVAL);
SELECT * FROM ORA;

--HERE IN USER IT START FROM 2 AND FROM DBA START FROM 1


--DROP TABLE ORA;
--DROP SEQUENCE SEQ_ORA;
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7fe67ee643d79bfe4cd6ebd4f4d75b31)

Comment: Are you on 11.2.0.1? This looks like the behaviour in that version with deferred segment creation - see MoS note 1050193.1. Not sure what you mean by the DBA comment but that might also make sense if you mean in the SYS schema, which behaves differently to normal accounts. Can you verify what happens if you repeat your test but explicitly add `segment creation deferred` and `segment creation immediate` to the `create table` statement, as a normal user?

Answer (score 0):

This was the sort-of expected behaviour in Oracle 11.2.0.1 with deferred segment creation.

If you have access to Oracle support you can look at [document 1050193.1](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/1050193_1.html), which shows the same thing happening.

You can change your table creation statement to:

```
CREATE TABLE ORA(ID NUMBER) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
```

You can also change the default behaviour via the `deferred_segment_creation` system parameter.

---

In a comment in your example code you said:

> HERE IN USER IT START FROM 2 AND FROM DBA START FROM 1

I assume that 'DBA' means you tested this in the SYS schema (which generally isn't a good idea). Deferred segment creation doesn't apply there; [from the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF54479):

> **Restrictions on Deferred Segment Creation**
> This clause is subject to the following restrictions:
>
> - You cannot defer segment creation for the following types of tables: index-organized tables, clustered tables, global temporary tables, session-specific temporary tables, internal tables, typed tables, AQ tables, external tables, and tables owned by SYS, SYSTEM, PUBLIC, OUTLN, or XDB.